# Clearing floats? Or something else?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this website for my dad:
http://smartcampusdeals.com/TendonAiD/index3.html

and the three columns (with the stick cartoony people) extend past the container. Right now, I have the container set at a static height (700px or something) but I want the height to adjust, so I don't have to change it for every other page. Why are these three columns behaving that way and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what is wrong? I don't see anything that looks bad for those three middle columns.

Comment: I'm at work so I don't have access to the FTP to change it, but basically that big white container that has all the text and those three columns only extends to like 3/4 of the way down the columns. it cuts off like its a float problem. I used a div with clear: both and that didn't work. so my temporary fix was to set a static height

Answer (score 5):

This is the classic 'collapsed parent' problem, created by floating an element, but not its parent. In your case you have a float on `#feature-text` and its children, but not `#content-wrapper`.

There are four CSS solutions, although one of the main two should work for you:

Either add another clear float - `<div class="clear"></div>` - at the end of the content wrapper, or give the content wrapper the css `overflow:hidden`.

This good article explains the theory and the other two possible solutions:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

Answer (score 1):

I've used several different approaches for this problem in the past.

The best one so far is:

`#logos { zoom: 1; overflow: hidden; }`

Basically just setting the container of the floats to `overflow: hidden` or `auto` fixes this behavior in most browsers.

Of course this doesn't always work in IE (what else is new). That's what the `zoom: 1;` is for.